# how to set custom url with query string to action route .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, url-routing

```
 [Route("/xxx-xxxx")]
    public IActionResult GoToXxxx()
    {
      return View();
    }
```

this is my code above and I want to set another route like:

```
 [Route("/xxx-xxxx?l=1")]
```

I can do it with RoutePrefix in .net, but in .net core I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1.use `http://localhost:35035/xxx-xxxx/{lValue here}`

```
[Route("/xxx-xxxx/{l:int}")]
    public IActionResult GoToXxxx(int l)
    {
      return View();
    }
```

Here is a demo:

Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        [Route("GetUser/{l:int}")]
        public IActionResult Index(int l)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

test url:

```
https://localhost:44379/api/User/GetUser/1
```

result:
[image]

2.both `http://localhost:35035/xxx-xxxx` and `http://localhost:35035/xxx-xxxx?l={lValue}` will go to the action

```
[Route("/xxx-xxxx")]
    public IActionResult GoToXxxx(string id)
    {
      return View();
    }
```

Comment: still it goes to localhost:35035/api/user/GetUser/erol, i want to set url with query string to my route

Comment: What do you mean you will still go to localhost:35035/api/user/GetUser/erol,if you want to set route,you cannot use ?=xxxx

Comment: sorry, it is my fault. It works, there was another problem and i figure out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
// xxx-xxxx => GetUser
// l => name

[HttpGet("GetUser/{name}")]
public string GetUser(string name)
{
    return "Hi" + name;
}
```

This will work like this:

http://localhost:35035/api/user/GetUser?name=erol

Comment: it is not working, this is coming like http://localhost:35035/api/user/GetUser/erol